# Moustache template for Swagger codegen static documentation - responseMessages

Tags: json, templates, mustache

I am trying to use swagger-codegen to generate static-docs.

The docs are generated based on Moustache templates that are included in the project.

When I run it with the sample JSON from wordnik Swagger api-docs, it generates everything perfectly (every api has it's own .file like Pet.html, User.html), but when I try to run it with similar JSON of mine, it generates only 1 operations file containing all the methods of my REST api.

Wordnik JSON reponse can be found at [worndik JSON api](http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/api/api-docs)

Mine API response looks like this:

```
{"apiVersion":"1.0","swaggerVersion":"1.2","apis":[{"path":"/default/countries","description":"Operations about countries"},{"path":"/default/gateways","description":"Operations on payment gateways"},{"path":"/default/location","description":"Operations about locations"},{"path":"/default/mccs","description":"Operations about MCCs"},{"path":"/default/merchants","description":"Operations about merchants"},{"path":"/default/partners","description":"Operations about partners"},{"path":"/default/payments","description":"Operations about payments"},{"path":"/default/resources","description":"Operations about resources"},{"path":"/default/terminals","description":"Operations about terminals"},{"path":"/default/terminalsubsetdefaultresourceset","description":"Operations about terminalSubsetDefaultResourceSet"},{"path":"/default/users","description":"Operations about users"}],"info":{"title":"my API","description":"","termsOfServiceUrl":"","contact":"","license":"","licenseUrl":""}}
```

Also, I would like to extract ReponseMessage Codes in every operation that has them in JSON. I tried to add

`{{#ResponseMessages}}
    <h3 class="responseMessages">{{message}}</h3>
    {{/ResponseMessages}}`

to operations.model, but It doesn't work (not with myApi, nor with Wordnik) (I have similar JSON like this:[JSON with responseCodes](http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/api/api-docs/pet)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the following (at least it works for me), based on the current version of [Codegen.scala](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/wordnik/swagger/codegen/Codegen.scala)

```
    {{#errorList}}
    {{code}} {{reason}} {{responseModel}}
    {{/errorList}}
```